# gpiozero generating io.TextIOWrapper 'noise' when getting load_average

Tags: python-3.x, gpiozero

I'm trying to use gpiozero LoadAverage to get the average system load for display on a small OLED plate. The problem is, any time I try to assign LoadAverage().load_average to a variable, it generates a

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/proc/loadavg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the load average from gpiozero without it generating these messages?  I'm not a python programmer so I'm trying to hack stuff together into the adafruit stats.py script.

Comment: Ditto, its some trace in the lower levels, but without a remote debugger, not possible to find the source of the errant printing statement.

Comment: There seems to be an open issue on GitHub regarding this issue, in case it's still relevant. see https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/issues/983

Comment: cool thanks - I'll see if their release is updated yet